# Who gets to use a reanimated Gamekeeper's ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing a clunky [Gamekeeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15230) build of mine against a Legacy Reanimator deck when the following situation occurred:

I had a [Leyline of the Void](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205013) in play (don't know if it's relevant). I had a [Gamekeeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15230) in my own graveyard which my opponent reanimated with [Animate Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=265167). I destroyed the [Gamekeeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15230) with a [Slaughter Pact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=130704).

**Who gets to use Gamekeeper's ability?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your opponent. [Leyline of the Void](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20the%20Void) has no bearing in this situation, because the Gatekeeper is going to your (its owner's graveyard).

> 400.3. If an object would go to any library, graveyard, or hand other than its owner’s, it goes to its owner’s corresponding zone.

When an object refers to **you**, it means its controller.

> Card Text: When Gamekeeper dies, **you** may exile it. If you do, reveal cards from the top of your library until you reveal a creature card. Put that card onto the battlefield and put all other cards revealed this way into your graveyard.

> 109.5. The words “you” and “your” on an object refer to the object’s controller, its would-be controller (if a player is attempting to play, cast, or activate it), or its owner (if it has no controller). For a static ability, this is the current controller of the object it’s on. For an activated ability, this is the player who activated the ability. **For a triggered ability, this is the controller of the object when the ability triggered**, unless it’s a delayed triggered ability. To determine the controller of a delayed triggered ability, see rules 603.7d–f.